# Does Azure VM agent installed on on-premises machine posts data to Azure/Any service related to azure/any other URL?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

I have observed that the azure VM agent installed in the on-premises machine is collecting some logs related to my machine and stored in "C:\WindowsAzure" location. I am concerned whether this data is posted to Azure/Any service related to azure/any other URL?

By the way, I have installed the Azure VM agent to create an Azure compatible image.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#windows-guest-agent-automatic-logs-collection) document, Windows Guest Agent has a feature to automatically collect some logs. This feature is controller by the CollectGuestLogs.exe process. It exists for both PaaS Cloud Services and IaaS Virtual Machines and its goal is to quickly & automatically collect some diagnostics logs from a VM - so they can be used for offline analysis. The collected logs are Event Logs, OS Logs, Azure Logs and some registry keys. It produces a ZIP file that is transferred to the VM’s Host. This ZIP file can then be looked at by Engineering Teams and Support professionals to investigate issues on request of the customer owning the VM.

[Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44852) is an open GitHub issue on how to disable it when needed. Keep an eye on it for updates in the future.